# The links do/does provide useful information(article)

Tags: articles

This is about article usage+do

> "The links **do/does** provide useful information.''

As you can see, I have just used 'the'(article) followed by 'links'(plural) and then what's next?

> Should I use '**does**' from using '**the**', ***OR***
>
> '**does**' from using **'links'**(plural noun)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definite article (**the**) does not require the use of a singular verb. The form of the verb is controlled by the form of the noun:

> The **link** provide**s** useful information.
>   The **links** provide useful information.